Factor Analysis with Multiple Imputation
I have a dataset with 49 Items of a questionnaire (ordinal; 0,1,2,3,4) with 5 diagnostic group of samples (n1: 50, n2: 25; n3:30, n4:23, n5:60). However, the dataset have missings like for 10-12 individuals up to 10% missings across all items; missing at random). I want to conduct a factor analysis in R like with the principal function of the "psych" package with 9 factor solution and varimax rotation.
My question is how can I conduct a multiple imputation and pool the factor loadings and other PCA parameters (e.g., explained variance, item complexity, commonalities)
Single imputation works fine with the mice package using "polr" (proportional odds logistic regression). However I want to do the multiple imputation to have most possible accurate results.
I can conduct PCAs with all imputed datasets:
completed_data_1 <- complete(imputed_data, 1)
completed_data_2 <- complete(imputed_data, 2)

completed_data_1[items] <- lapply(completed_data_1[items], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
completed_data_2[items] <- lapply(completed_data_2[items], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

pca_result_1 <- principal(completed_data_1[, items], nfactors = 9, rotate = "varimax")
pca_result_2 <- principal(completed_data_2[, items], nfactors = 9, rotate = "varimax")

But how can I pool other parameters of the PCAs taking into account the variances? Which method can I use in R for this pooling?

You can pool any normally distributed statistic by taking the mean. Depending on the statistic of interest (e.g. correlation coefficients), you may have to transform it before taking the mean and back-transform it afterwards. Have a look at this vignette to see how to handle some common statistics. See also this answer to a similar question.
